# Opening a popup with iFrame on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working on this project which requires this feature.
When I hover over an image, it should open a small box next to it (like tooltip) and load a link there (probably an iFrame).

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script
```

I tried to do this via tooltip (tried manipulating the tolltip so that it could open a small box and load an iFrame), but that didn't work as well.
Due to my limited knowledge in JavaScript/ jQuery. I couldn't find any viable solution.

What should I do to make it work like require ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPdp7/1/)

the html:

```
<div id="hoverMe">Hover over here</div>
<iframe id="tooltip" src="http://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>
```

the jQuery:

```
$('#hoverMe').hover(function () {
    $('#tooltip').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $('#tooltip').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly mate.
But when I try to hover over the popup that was opened..it disappears.
How can I make it stay there when I hover over it ?

Also, how would I be able to display the popup on the right side ?