# How to show live preview in a small popup of linked page on mouse over on link in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do a popup on hover on a link, I found and tried the code which is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a>
<div class="box">
<iframe src="http://getbootstrap.com/" width = "500px" height = "500px">
</iframe>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I got the output from the above code, Now I want to try it in the MVC, I tried to do it, below is my MVC Code:

```
   <div class="col-md-6">
    @if (@item.Linkreviewsothersite != null)
            {
                    <p class="readmore text-right"><a id="showreview" href="@item.Linkreviewsothersite"> Reviews</a></p>
                        <div id="reviewbox" class="embed-responsive-4by3 hidden">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://getbootstrap.com/"></iframe>
                        </div>
                }
   </div>
$('#showreview').hover(function () {
    $('#reviewbox').css({
        display: "block",
        position: "relative", 
        zindex: "100"
});
})
```

when I tried to do it in the above code I'm missing something, can someone help me plz..

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of achieving this would be to use:

```
<div id="hoverMe">Hover over here</div>
<iframe id="tooltip" src="http://jsfiddle.net"></iframe>
```

jQuery - see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPdp7/1/)

```
$('#hoverMe').hover(function () {
    $('#tooltip').fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $('#tooltip').fadeOut();
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818815/opening-a-popup-with-iframe-on-mouseover) for reference